# PEP-8 not working in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pep8, pep8-checker

I'm trying to use PEP-8 style formatting in Eclipse, but I can't make it work. My settings are correct, they are on the following screenshot: [image]

But there are no warnings in my code caused by pep8, it is not working. But if we take a look at the error log of Eclipse, we see the following error list:
[image]

I tried to use an other Eclipse version, but it had no effect. The Python version is 3.3. Any ideas, what can be the problem?

Comment: What's the symptom of it not working?

Comment: There are no warnings in my code, which should be caused by pep8.

Comment: Why the downvotes, is my question not clear?